# Coarsened Exact Matching with MatchIt returns error

Tags: r, matching

When I try to implement Coarsened Exact Matching with the MatchIt package I get the following error:

`` Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, gn[g], value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 6 ``

Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(MatchIt)
require(cem)

d <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6 , 
  treat = rep(c(1,0),each = 3),
  group = c("A","B","C" , "B" , "B" , "B"))

matchit(formula = treat ~ class , 
        data = d , 
        grouping = list(group = list(c("A" , "B"))),
        method = "cem")
```

I am running version 1.1.19 of cem and 3.0.2 of MatchIt.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the `matchit` function applies `model.matrix` to your data (code [here](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/blob/master/R/matchit.R)).  This means that the dataframe actually fed into the `cem` function no longer has a column called `group` (it has `groupA`, `groupB`, etc.).  So `cem` doesn't know what to do with the `group` element of the `grouping` list.

As far as I can see, the only way to accomplish what you want is to use `cem` directly, something like this:

```
mat = cem(treatment = "treat",
          drop = "id",
          data = d,
          grouping = list(group = list(c("A" , "B"))))
```